# How to retrieve value of XML element using a Nokogiri SAX Parser?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, sax

How does one access the text value of a nested element using a Nokogiri SAX parser?

```
require 'nokogiri'

  xml = <<-eos
   <sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
      <sitemap>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/example-sitemap.xml</loc>
     </sitemap>
    </sitemapindex>
  eos

  class MySAXDoc < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document
     def start_element name, attrs=[]
        if name == "sitemap"
          # from here, how can one retrieve the value of the child element, `loc`?
        end
     end
  end

  sax_parser = Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser.new(MySAXDoc.new)
  sax_parser.parse(xml)
```

Comment: I am also stuck with same problem.. Have you got any other answer expect below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read ahead, so you must keep track of the current context within the file yourself.  Something along these lines should do the trick:

```
def start_element(name, attrs = [])
  @element = name

  if name == 'sitemap'
    @sitemap = true
  end
end

def end_element(name)
  @element = nil

  if name == 'sitemap'
    @sitemap = false
  end
end

def characters(string)
  if @element == 'loc' && @sitemap
    # The local variable 'string' holds the text contents of the <loc> tag
    # so do something with it here
    puts string
  end
end
```

How this works: When a new element is started it checks to see if it is a  and if so sets a @sitemap variable.  On the next iteration when the element is  it checks @sitemap to see if it is within a sitemap and does something with its contents.